# Inserting a large object with GridFS

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

Since MongoDB itself has at the moment a limit of 16MB per document, I've being trying to use GridFS to overcome the obstacle.

At the moment, my code looks something like:

```
const string INPUT_FILE = @"C:\Users\...\CP001814.gbk";

// Set up connection to database
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("genomedb");
MongoGridFS grid = new MongoGridFS(server, "genomedb", new MongoGridFSSettings());

// do something with the input file which returns an ISequence 'sequence' object

MongoGridFSStream stream = grid.Create("CP003814.gbk");
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, sequence);
MongoGridFSFileInfo info = db.GridFS.Upload(stream, "CP003814.gbk_sequence");
stream.Close();
```

What I'm I doing wrong here? Currently when I run it it creates the fs.files file metadata, length = 0, and nothing on fs.chunks.

Comment: What is the stream? How about reset the "Position" of stream to 0?